# Rails select_all deserialize Postgresql array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I make a custom query that returns rows with array value **term_names**

```
Product.connection.select_all("
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(terms.name), vocabularies.name vocabulary_name
  FROM terms
  INNER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.id = terms.vocabulary_id
  GROUP BY vocabulary_name")

| term_names                                                     | vocabulary_name |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------|
| {{76,Yellow},{77,Green},{79,Blue}.                             | Color           |
```

But the problem is that Rails does not want to convert {...} into ruby array and returns it as string.

```
[{"array_agg"=>"{Yellow,Green,Blue}", "vocabulary_name"=>"Color"}]
```

How can I make Rails parse result and return nested array instead?

Comment: what Rails version are you?

Comment: You're pretty much using ruby wrongly ... But in any case you're asking your database to return a string. If you want it to be an array, you'll need to use `split`, and/or set up a model to talk to the "terms" table, then use ruby to do the grouping

Comment: @JoelBlum its Rails 6

Answer (score 4):

You (me) should call cast_values method

```
Product.connection.select_all("
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(terms.name), vocabularies.name vocabulary_name
  FROM terms
  INNER JOIN vocabularies ON vocabularies.id = terms.vocabulary_id
  GROUP BY vocabulary_name").cast_values
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well so I extended **ActiveRecord::Result** with a `to_cast_hash` method:

```
class ActiveRecord::Result

  # NOTE: calling .to_hash turns all values, including arrays, into strings, 
  # while calling .cast_values returns an array without the column keys.
  # This method returns a hash of the results with properly cast values:
  def to_cast_hash
    cast_rows = self.cast_values
    cols = self.columns
    cast_hashes = []
    cast_rows.each do |row|
      h = {}
      cols.each_with_index do |col,index|
        h[col] = row[index]
      end
      cast_hashes.push(h)
    end
    return cast_hashes
  end
  
end
```